# Netbeans code template - do not work outside php markup

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete, netbeans-7, code-templates

Lately I have been working with some WordPress template and NetBeans.

I would like to use code templating functionality outside of the `<?php ?>` markup.

All works fine as long as use `tab` inside the `<?php ?>`. But, in WordPress templates there is mix of `html / php` code inside `.php` file,  so usually you are pasting something like this:

`<?php the_title(); ?>` which is initially outside of other `<?php ?>`

Any idea how to create code template working in NeatBeans in `PHP file`, but outside of the `<?php ?>` markup?

Comment: Welcome to wordpress. Netbeans needs those `<?php ... ?>` segments to know that you're actually using PHP and not HTML. You might be able to configure Netbeans so you have the common pastes on hotkeys or from a list you can double-click and you *might* be able to extend Netbeans HTML template to offer autocomplete for readymade PHP chunks, however I'm not fluent with Netbeans so you need to look up the Netbeans manual how to do any of these.

Comment: Um, so what's the problem? And what works fine as long as using the `tab`? What happens when not using the `tab`? Been working with netbeans since it's release and syntax highlighting is the least of its problems .. mixing different syntaxes in single lines does create problems for some languages, but when using (designating) `<?php ?>` tags inside template syntaxes (Smarty, Twig, etc), it should just work fine.

Comment: Got it working! Putted my snippets under HTML and they work fine in `.php` file without `<?php ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools,Options,Editor, select Language = HTML and add whatever abbreviation you want, for example:

Abbreviation: t
Expanded text:

Save it and to use it press t + [TAB]